# Show files on FTP in a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ftp

We have an FTP site for clients, and they just go to it with a web browser and see the files.  I'd like to display the files in a more visually pleasing manner, is there a way I can show what files are on the server in the view, perhaps iterate over them and style them?

I found this answer here, but really didn't answer my question:

[Ruby-Rails serve ftp file direct to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722169/ruby-rails-serve-ftp-file-direct-to-client)

(using rails 3 if it makes a difference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use library links below:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/index.html

http://oreilly.com/catalog/ruby/chapter/ch04.html

and you can use EventMachine  https://github.com/schleyfox/em-ftp-client.

Cheers!

Comment: `list` or `ls` command is there in  http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-ls. Please have a look