# URL encryption in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, encryption

I'm using my own ftp to host some files. When users see them, they see a url like ftp://mydomain.com/xyz/file.pdf

I don't want to host them anywhere else. Is there any way I can hide mydomain.com from users?

Comment: You can replace the domain name with the IP address of the server if it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

[Ruby-Rails serve ftp file direct to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722169/ruby-rails-serve-ftp-file-direct-to-client)

Basically you will be setting up your rails server to act as a proxy, so the request goes to your rails server, it fetches the file and then sends it.

You'll have to consider memory/load, but it will hide your ftp! It should then be possible to secure your ftp with a password to further protect your files.